Understanding the proof of $L^p(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ is complete ($1\leq p<+\infty$)
Background
I have some questions when reading the proof of $L^p(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ is complete for $1\leq p<+\infty$. The proof is proceeded by showing that each absolutely convergent series in $L^p(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ is convergent:

Suppose that $1\leq p<+\infty$ and that $\{f_k\}$ is a sequence of functions that belong to $\mathscr{L}^p(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ and satisfy $\sum_k\|f_k\|_p<+\infty$. Define $g:X\to[0,+\infty]$ by
$$
g(x)=\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|f_k(x)|\right)^p
$$
(of course $(+\infty)^p=+\infty$). Minkowski's inequality, applied to the function $|f_k|$, implies
$$
\left(\int\left(\sum_{k=1}^n|f_k|\right)^pd\mu\right)^{\frac{1}{p}} = \left\|\sum_{k=1}^n|f_k|\right\|_p \leq \sum_{k=1}^n\|f_k\|_p
$$
holds for each $n$, and so it follows from the monotone convergence theorem that
$$
\int gd\mu = \lim_{n\to\infty}\int\left(\sum_{k=1}^n|f_k|\right)^pd\mu \leq \left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\|f_k\|_p\right)^p;
$$
thus $g$ is integrable. Consequently $g(x)$ is finite for almost every $x$ (Corollary 2.3.14), and the series $\sum_kf_k(x)$ is absolutely convergent, and hence convergent, for almost every $x$. Define a function $f$ on $X$ by
\begin{align*}
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f_k(x)\quad &\text{if $g(x)<+\infty$},\\
\\
0\quad &\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
Then $f$ is measurable and satisfies $|f|^p\leq g$, and so it belongs to $\mathscr{L}^p(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$. Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\sum_{k=1}^nf_k(x)-f(x)\right|=0$ and $\left|\sum_{k=1}^nf_k(x)-f(x)\right|^p\leq g(x)$ hold for almost every $x$, the dominated convergence theorem implies that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\|\sum_{k=1}^nf_k-f\right\|_p=0$. The completeness of $L^p(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ follows.

My Questions
Here are my questions:

In order to apply the monotone convergence theorem, we need $g$ and $\left(\sum_{k=1}^n|f_k|\right)^p$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ to be $[0,+\infty]$-valued $\mathscr{A}$-measurable functions. But why are they?

Why is the integrability of $g$ follows from that inequality?

Why is $f$ $\mathscr{A}$-measurable?

Why is $|f|^p\leq g$?

Why is $|f|^p\in\mathscr{L}^p(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$?

Why does $\left|\sum_{k=1}^nf_k(x)-f(x)\right|^p\leq g(x)$ hold for almost every $x$?

How does $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\|\sum_{k=1}^nf_k-f\right\|_p=0$ follow in the end?


My Attempt
I tried to answer these questions myself one-by-one, and here is my attempt:

Note that for each positive integer $k$ the function $f_k$ is complex-valued and $\mathscr{A}$-measurable, thus $|f_k|$ is nonnegative real-valued $\mathscr{A}$-measurable, and so $\sum_{k=1}^n|f_k|$ is nonnegative real-valued $\mathscr{A}$-measurable.  For each positive integer $n$ let $F_n = \left(\sum_{k=1}^n|f_k|\right)^p$. Clearly $F_n$ is nonnegative real-valued. We now prove that $F_n$ is $\mathscr{A}$-measurable. For any $t\leq0$, we have
$$
\{x\in X:F_n(x)<t\}=\emptyset\in\mathscr{A}.
$$
For any $t>0$, we have
\begin{align*}
\{x\in X:F_n(x)<t\} &= \left\{x\in X:\left(\sum_{k=1}^n|f_k(x)|\right)^p<t\right\}\\
&= \left\{x\in X:\sum_{k=1}^n|f_k(x)|<t^{\frac{1}{p}}\right\}\\
&\in \mathscr{A}.
\end{align*}
Thus $F_n$ is a nonnegative real-valued $\mathscr{A}$-measurable function for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Moreover, for each $x\in X$ and for each positive integer $n$ the sequence $\{F_n(x)\}$ satisfies $F_n(x)\geq0$ and $F_n(x)\leq F_{n+1}$, thus $\lim_{n\to\infty}F_n(x)$ is either a positive number or equal to $+\infty$. So $g=\lim_{n\to\infty}F_n = \left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|f_k(x)|\right)^p$ is well defined and it is a $[0,+\infty]$-valued $\mathscr{A}$-measurable function.

The Minkowski's inequality implies
$$
\left(\int F_nd\mu\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}\leq\sum_{k=1}^n\|f_k\|_p
$$
holds for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Then this inequality, together with monotone convergence theorem and the convergence of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\|f_k\|_p$, imply
\begin{align*}
\int gd\mu &= \lim_{n\to\infty}\int F_nd\mu = \lim_{n\to\infty}\int\left(\sum_{k=1}^n|f_k|\right)^pd\mu\\
&\leq \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\|f_k\|_p\right)^p = \left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\|f_k\|_p\right)^p < +\infty
\end{align*}
(note that the existence of the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int\left(\sum_{k=1}^n|f_k|\right)^pd\mu$ is implied by the monotone convergence theorem). Since $g$ is $[0,+\infty]$-valued, it follows that $g^+=g$ and $g^-=0$, and so $\int g^+d\mu$ and $\int g^-d\mu$ are both finite, which implies $g$ is integrable.

Let $A=\{x\in X:g(x)<+\infty\}$. Write $f$ as
\begin{align*}
f &= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f_k\chi_A\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^nf_k\chi_A\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}h_n,
\end{align*}
where $h_n = \sum_{k=1}^nf_k\chi_A$. We prove that $A\in\mathscr{A}$. We know that $g$ is $\mathscr{A}$-measurable. Define $p:X\to[0,+\infty]$ by $p(x)=+\infty$ for all $x\in X$. Then $\{x\in X: p(x)<t\}=\emptyset\in\mathscr{A}$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$, and thus $p$ is $\mathscr{A}$-measurable. Therefore, $A = \{x\in X:g(x)<p(x)\}\in\mathscr{A}$, and so $A^c\in\mathscr{A}$. Next, note that for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$, $f_k$ is $\mathscr{A}$-measurable. Moreover, for $t\leq0$, $\{x\in X:\chi_A(x)<t\}=\emptyset\in\mathscr{A}$; for $t>1$, $\{x\in X:\chi_A(x)<t\} = X\in\mathscr{A}$; for $1<t\leq1$, $\{x\in X:\chi_A(x)<t\} = A^c\in\mathscr{A}$. Thus, $h_n$ is $\mathscr{A}$-measurable, and so $f=\lim_{n\to\infty}h_n$ is $\mathscr{A}$-measurable.

If $x\in A$, then $|f(x)|^p = \left|\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\right|^p \leq \left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|f_k(x)|\right)^p = g(x)$. If $x\notin A$, then $|f(x)|^p=0\leq g(x)$.

We first prove that $|f|^p$ is $\mathscr{A}$-measurable. If $t\leq0$, then $\{x\in X:|f(x)|^p<t\}=\emptyset\in\mathscr{A}$. If $t>0$, then $\{x\in X:|f(x)|^p<t\} = \{x\in X:|f(x)|<t^{\frac{1}{p}}\}\in\mathscr{A}$ because $f$ and thus $|f|$ is $\mathscr{A}$-measurable. Therefore, $|f|^p$ is a $[0,+\infty]$-valued $\mathscr{A}$-measurable function. We know that $g$ is also a $[0,+\infty]$-valued $\mathscr{A}$-measurable functions. The integrability of $g$ implies that $\int gd\mu = \int g^+d\mu < +\infty$. Then $|f|^p\leq g$ implies $\int|f|^pd\mu\leq\int gd\mu <+\infty$. Since $\left(|f|^p\right)^+=|f|^p$ and $\left(|f|^p\right)^- = 0$, we have $|f|^p$ is integrable, and so $|f|^p\in\mathscr{L}^p(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$.

If $x\in A$, then
\begin{align*}
\left|\sum_{k=1}^nf_k(x) - f(x)\right|^p &= \left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}f_k(x)\right|^p\\
&= \lim_{m\to\infty}\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^mf_k(x)\right|^p\\
&\leq \lim_{m\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=n+1}^m|f_k(x)|\right)^p\\
&= \left(\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}|f_k(x)|\right)^p\\
&\leq \left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|f_k(x)|\right)^p\\
&= g(x).
\end{align*}
Thus, $\left|\sum_{k=1}^nf_k(x)-f(x)\right|^p\leq g(x)$ holds for almost every $x$.

We know that $g$ is a $[0,+\infty]$-valued integrable function on $X$. Define functions $q$ and $q_1,q_2,\dots$ by $q=0$ and $q_n = \left|\sum_{k=1}^nf_k-f\right|^p$. Then for all $x\in A$, $q=\lim_{n\to\infty}q_n$, and so $q=\lim_{n\to\infty}q_n$ holds $\mu$-almost everywhere. Also, $|q_n|<g$ holds $\mu$-almost everywhere. So the dominated convergence theorem implies $0=\int qd\mu = \lim_{n\to\infty}\int q_nd\mu$ and so $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\int q_nd\mu\right)^{\frac{1}{p}} = 0$. Hence  $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\int\left|\sum_{k=1}^nf_k-f\right|^pd\mu\right)^{\frac{1}{p}} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\|\sum_{k=1}^nf_k-f\|_p = \|\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^nf_k - f\|_p = \|\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f_k - f\|_p = 0$. Therefore, $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f_k = f \in\mathscr{L}^p(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$.


Where I Have Trouble
My main concern is my attempt to Question 7. There are mainly two of them:
First, I claimed that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int q_nd\mu=0$ implies $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\int q_nd\mu\right)^{\frac{1}{p}} = 0$. But I am not sure whether this is legit, because I have never seen a "power law of limit of sequence" from any analysis textbook. Basically, if $p\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = a\in[-\infty,+\infty]$, does this imply $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n^p = a^p$? I don't think this is correct, because $a^p$ may not even be defined (consider for example square root of a negative number or the denominator is zero). But what if $a_n\in[0,+\infty]$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $p\in\mathbb{R}_+$? How can we generalize such a result (in its most general possible case) and prove it?
Secone, I claimed that the limit of norm is the norm of limit. But is this true? Why? Basically, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\|\sum_{k=1}^nf_k-f\right\|_p = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\int\left|\sum_{k=1}^nf_k - f\right|^pd\mu\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}$, but is this equal to $\left(\int\left|\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f_k-f\right|^pd\mu\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}$? Why?
Last but not least, I know this is a lot to ask, but just in case you are interested in the proof, I would really appreciate it if you could help me check whether my answer to the other questions are correct.
Thank you very much in advance!

Reference:$\quad$ Theorem 3.4.1 from Measure Theory by Donald Cohn

I might look at your solutions to the other points tomorrow. Very briefly:
You can notice $(4)$ and $(2)$ give $(5)$. $(1),(2),(3)$ all follow just from the explicit estimates you have in the post and the nice reality that measurable $\Bbb R$-valued functions are closed under pointwise limits and pasting together on measurable sets, it really just comes from that (one of the reasons the Lebesgue formulation is so powerful). Technically speaking - and this does come back to a quibble you had about $7$ - we should observe that $(\sum)^p$ is in fact the limit of the partial sums to the power $p$ here, each of which are measurable (because ! the composition of a measurable function followed by a continuous function is measurable) and the summands are nonnegative, so we can just look at $[0,\infty]$ where $()^p$ behaves well. As for actually proving $(4)$, well, is it not essentially immediate from the definition of $f$ and of $g$? All you have to do is note $|\sum|\le\sum|-|$. $(6)$ is just because $|\sum_{k=1}^n-\sum_{k=1}^\infty|=|\sum_{k=n}^\infty|\le\sum_{k=1}^\infty|-|$, and because $y\mapsto y^p$ is an increasing function, but notice the "for almost every $x$" actually refers to the condition before as well, that $\lim_n|-|=0$ pointwise. In fact the inequality in question $(6)$ holds for all $x$ (but the other condition does not).
For $(7)$,... yes, $y\mapsto y^a$, $[0,\infty]\to[0,\infty]$, is continuous if $a>0$. This (and actually defining $y^p$) is a fact/task from introductory real analysis, and you've been doing far more difficult things with measure theory! The only possible problem could be at zero, but hopefully you acknowledge that $y^a$ can be made arbitrarily small as desired (which is all you need to say). So the dominated convergence theorem literally says, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int|\sum_{k=1}^nf_k(x)-f(x)|^p=0$. Now, you can happily raise that to the $a=1/p$th power and still have limit zero, this really is legitimate. There is no grand general theorem one needs to apply here; exponentiation is continuous. Now this says, if $s_n:=\sum_{k=1}^nf_k$, that $\|s_n-f\|^p\to0$. But that's exactly what you wanted! No one is trying to say that this is equal to $\|\sum_{k=1}^\infty f_k-f\|$, but that is true!, because this statement has no content; $f$ is defined a.e. to equal that series so of course the difference between $f$ and this series is zero (.. which is the limit of the norms). More generally, it is a good exercise to show for any normed linear space that the norm is continuous, so that yes, really, you can pass limits under the norm sign if (!) you already know this limit is a strong limit in the sense of the norm you're working with. Here, we knew $\sum_{k=1}^nf_k\to f$ ... in some a priori weaker pointwise sense, so we can't a priori move swap the limit and the norm. That's what the dominated convergence theorem's good for! But if you already knew you had norm convergence, say $h_n\to h$ in norm then $\|h_n-q\|\to\|h-q\|$ for any element $q$.
And to go from here to actually proving the Lebesgue space is complete, one plays a game with rapid Cauchy subsequences and taking some such sequence $(f_n)$ and looking at the series $f_1+(f_2-f_1)+(f_3-f_2)+\cdots$ etc. and this absolutely converges in norm, if one has a rapid Cauchy sequence, and you can apply the above; that this has a limit means exactly that $(f_n)_n$ has a limit, by construction.

Thank you so much! This is very helpful! Just want to make sure I get your point (mainly for Question 7), is the answer I posted below what you meant?

We may generalize the result of power law of sequential limit as follows:

Lemma$\quad$ Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence such that for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $a_n\in[0,+\infty]$. Let $p$ be a positive real number. Suppose that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = a \in [0,+\infty]$. Then $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n^p = \left(\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\right)^p = a^p$.
Proof$\quad$ Consider first the case that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = a = +\infty$. Let $M\geq0$, and so $M^{\frac{1}{p}}\geq0$. Then there is an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n\geq N$ implies $a_n\geq M^{\frac{1}{p}}$, and so $a_n^p\geq M$. Thus $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n^p = +\infty = (+\infty)^p = a^p$.
Next, consider the case that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = a \in\mathbb{R}_+$. Define a function $f:\mathbb{R}_+\to\mathbb{R}_+$ by $f(x) = x^p$. Then $f$ is a continuous function; in particular, $f$ is continuous at the point $a$, and so $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = f(a) = a^p$. Hence, $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n^p = \lim_{n\to\infty}f(a_n) = a^p$.

Now let us restate the proof of the final part as follows:

We know that $g$ is a $[0,+\infty]$-valued integrable function on $X$. Define the function $q$ by $q=0$. For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ define the function $q_n$ by $q_n = \left|\sum_{k=1}^nf_k-f\right|^p$. Then clearly $q$ and $q_1,q_2,\dots$ are $[0,+\infty]$-valued $\mathscr{A}$-measruable functions. Note that for every $x\in A$, $\left|\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f_k(x)-f(x)\right| = 0$, and thus $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\sum_{k=1}^nf_k(x)-f(x)\right| = 0$, then the above lemma implies $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\sum_{k=1}^nf_k(x)-f(x)\right|^p = \lim_{n\to\infty}q_n(x) = 0$. So $\lim_{n\to\infty}q_n(x)=q(x)$ holds at $\mu$-almost every $x$ in $X$. From Question 6, we have shown that $\left|\sum_{k=1}^nf_k(x)-f(x)\right|^p = |q_n(x)| \leq g(x)$ hold for each $n$ at $\mu$-almost every $x$. Then by Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence Theorem, $\int qd\mu = \lim_{n\to\infty}\int q_n\mu$; that is,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int\left|\sum_{k=1}^nf_k-f\right|^pd\mu = 0.
$$
Then by the above lemma, we have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\int\left|\sum_{k=1}^nf_k-f\right|^pd\mu\right)^{\frac{1}{p}} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left\|\sum_{k=1}^nf_k-f\right\|_p = 0,
$$
which means $f\in\mathscr{L}^p(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ is the limit of the sequence of sums $\left\{\sum_{k=1}^nf_k\right\}$; or equivalently, the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f_k$ is convergent.


I used the follow result as well:

Lemma$\quad$ Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence such that for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $a_n\in[-\infty,+\infty]$. Suppose that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = a \in [-\infty,+\infty]$. Then $\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_n| = |a|$.


Hi. In your proof of the first lemma you don't handle the $a=0$ case. For the second part you say $q_1$ etc. are clearly measurable before even defining the $q_1,q_2,...$, I think this is just a typo. A more important point is $|\sum_{k=1}^nf_k(x)-f(x)|=0$ for almost every $x\in A$, not "every" as you say. Other than that I agree with this

@FShrike About that lemma, I am actually a bit confused about the case when the elements of the sequence ${a_n}$ are raised to the power of $0$, because isn't everything to the power of $0$ equals $1$? So this would imply that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n^0=1=a^0$, right?

@FShrike $A$ is defined to be ${x\in X:g(x)<+\infty}$. So $\left|\sum_{k=1}^nf_k(x)-f(x)\right|$ does hold for every $x\in A$. However, since $A^c$ is $\mu$-null, it follows that this relation holds at $\mu$-almost every $x\in X$.

For exponent zero it’s less interesting since by convention it all gets set to zero, but constant functions are certainly continuous. I forgot you had defined $A$ already in your question (it wasn’t in your answer so I thought you referred to the whole space) so yes, I take back that comment
